# Java script change clipboard notes

Tags: javascript

I have script that copy ID internal content to user clipboard (style CTRL+C)

IF the URL contain & and the script change it to `&amp;`.

How can i prevent it? i would like it to still be '&' and not `&amp;`

Thanks

HTML

```
    Link: <span id="faqURL"><?PHP echo 'http://'.SITE_ADDRESS_ROOT.'/index.php?page=search&search_type=faq&faqID='.$_GET['faqID']; ?></span> 
    <a onclick="copyToClipboard('faqURL')">Copy</a>
```

SCRIPT

```
function copyToClipboard(elementId) {
     var aux = document.createElement("input");
     aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);
     document.body.appendChild(aux);
     aux.select();
     document.execCommand("copy");
     document.body.removeChild(aux);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, and don't need to. `&amp;` is how HTML represents a `&` character.

If you want an HTML representation of some data, then you **need** `&amp;`.

If you *don't* want an HTML representation of some data, then don't use `innerHTML` in the first place. Use `textContent` to get a text representation instead.